# How to fix every element on the same position, when browser is resized?

Tags: css, fixed, element, scrollable

Anyone tell me that how to fix all elements with css, means whatever we do with the browser's height and width then elements should not move? or elements should not move relative to the browser' height and width and page should also be scroll able?

Comment: I believe you're looking for `position:absolute`.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but any css tutorial will teach you that... You just have to look for it a little!

Comment: Give the `body` element a fixed width and place your elements in it.

Comment: No I don't mind.I believe even sometimes experts do little mistakes , actually. I tried position: absolute but div is still moving when I resize my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `position: absolute` to an element will cause it remain fixed relative to the document. That is, it will scroll with the document.

Applying `position: fixed` will cause it to remain fixed relative to your browser window. That is, if you scroll the document it will not move.

With each of these `position` values, you can specify some combination of `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` to specify their position. For example, the following style will fix an element very close to the top right of the browser window (it will not scroll with the document):

```
.topright {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```